# Method that indicates whether a window has a titlebar and border?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I mean general windows applications, *not* windows forms.

Like the title says is there any method that indicates if a window has a titlebar and border? Is there some P/Invoke accessible method that can access this information?

Comment: This is one method you'll need:  [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetWindowLongPtr()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLongPtr.html) and pass it `GWL_STYLE` to get the window's style. Compare that style against `WS_CAPTION` (which implies `WS_BORDER`) to see if the window has a title bar and border.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) has a list of the standard window styles and their numeric values.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to get the height of the caption of a particular window?

Comment: @prw56 I'm not sure off hand - maybe something to do with getting system metrics. You should probably ask a new question for that.